# How to access community wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are “Community Wiki” posts on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow)

I saw the word 'community wiki' a lot, but I have no idea how to use it and don't even know where it is.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Community wiki is explained in great depth here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow).

In short, it does two things:

- Allows anyone with 100 rep to edit your question and answers (normally editing requires 2,000 rep)
- Upvotes, downvotes, etc do not affect your rep

To make your question or answer community wiki, check the checkbox just below and to the right of the editing box when editing the question or answer.

Once checked and saved you can't undo it.